# Docker to see Containers in a Bulk

Tags: python, docker, containers

You see I have one container up;
[image]

but there are so many other containers showing up on cmd. I like to see just one row as Docker Desktop. Is there any way to do that ?

```
C:\Users\my.user\py projects\apache_airflow>docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS                        PORTS                              NAMES
372a6f68dac6   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   2 days ago   Up About a minute             8080/tcp                           apache_airflow_airflow-scheduler_1
7cf50002a4ea   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   2 days ago   Up About a minute             8080/tcp                           apache_airflow_airflow-worker_1
1da18490999d   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   2 days ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp             apache_airflow_airflow-webserver_1
2dce2620e44d   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   2 days ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp   apache_airflow_flower_1
0a1287ef2fd9   postgres:13            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   5432/tcp                           apache_airflow_postgres_1
000587a7e7d0   redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp             apache_airflow_redis_1
```

Comment: Use docker-compose, which seems to be already the case here, unbenownst to you.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think the question is only about the display in cmd. That has nothing to do with compose imho. Probably you need tools like cut, grep, sed or use the awk for output foatting in cmd.

Comment: The GUI also shows six containers running. None of the containers on the CLI is named "apache_airflow". That's why I'm convinced that a composed setup is used here. Concerning those mentioned tools, don't: Docker CLI provides quite a few ways to inspect things and to select various fields from them. Use those!

Comment: Yeah, there is a docker-compose file for apache airflow. However I still expect to see that if there is only one line in Desktop, there should be the same in cli as well.